# Test failing with RSpec in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I am trying to run this test but for some reason its failing.

```
describe "User Pages" do
    subject { page }
    .
    .
describe "Sign up" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Sign Me Up" }
    .
    .
 describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "name",             with: "newuser"
    fill_in "Username",         with: "user254"
    fill_in "Email",            with: "user@yahoo.com"
    select  "Male",             from: "gender"        
    fill_in "Password",         with: "password"
    fill_in "Confirm Password", with: "password"
  end

  it "Should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end   
end
```

However, when I run the test I get this error

```
Failures:

  1) User Pages signup with valid information Should create a user
      Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
      # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

      Finished in 4.61 seconds
      35 examples, 1 failure

      Failed examples:

      rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:34 # User Pages signup with valid information Should create a user
```

This is my create action in my controller

```
def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'
   end
end
```

When I try signing up in the browser, signup is successfull. Is anything wrong with my test? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried outputting any errors on the @user object? That might provide you with some extra insight.

Answer (score 1):

check if the user is being saved on the controller:

```
def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   puts "valid? = #{@user.valid?.inspect}"
   if @user.save
     puts 'saved!'
     redirect_to @user
   else
     puts 'not saved'
     puts @user.errors.inspect
     render 'new'
    end
end
```

that will print the controller process and you will know what's happening

if nothing gets printed, then the problem is some before_filter that's preventing the create action to being called

Comment: This is what gets printed `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f8ff059f718 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "", email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, username: "", gender: "", remember_token: nil>, @messages={:password_digest=>["can't be blank"], :name=>["can't be blank"], :email=>["can't be blank", "is invalid"], :username=>["can't be blank"], :gender=>["can't be blank"],:password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"], :password_confirmation=>["can't be blank"]}>`

Comment: check that you are filling the right names of the form, I suppose the form fileds are something like "user[name]" or "user_name", not just "name" if you created them with the form_for helper, that's why the record has everything blank, params[:user] is empty, you are not filling the form the right way, inspect the form with a browser to see the form field's names/ids

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
it "Should create a user" do
    click_button submit
    User.count.should == 1
  end
```

Comment: I still get an error `Failure/Error: User.count.should == 1
       expected: 1
            got: 0 (using ==)`

Comment: then try to use @user.save! in your controller, then you should get an error why its not working